# Can a library avoid exposing its use of Timber?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, lint

I'm developing an Android app that uses an open source library which in turn uses [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber). (Not to be confused with [Timber](https://wordpress.org/plugins/timber-library/).) Timber includes some custom lint inspections, and the library "leaks" them into my project. At first this was only an annoyance, as Timber's lint inspections complain every time I use the standard Android `Log` class. But now an [old Timber issue](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber/issues/292) is suddenly breaking my build.

I want to submit a PRQ or at least inform the library authors how they can avoid exposing their use of Timber so it doesn't pollute my project. The library is built with Gradle.

Comment: if you dont want tinder dependency in your project just use implementation instead of api it should work

Comment: I suggest you make the changes you feel necessary and then submit a PR on GitHub.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The question is what those changes would be.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Your question does not have enough information for anyone to answer that. I would have towel clone the Timber repo from GitHub and debug it to figure it out. Feel free to do so yourself. Welcome to the profession of programming.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I've been at this for over 20 years. If you'd actually read the question, you'd know it's not about Timber, it's about a library that uses Timber. Pretend you're writing a library using Timber. How do you prevent Timber's lint inspections from being exposed to the users of your library? Simple question, probably easily answerable by someone who knows the intricacies of Gradle.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede did you try Cold Fire's suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Since we're talking about a 3rd party lib, there isn't much you can do from inside your project aside from forking the lib and modifying it, or ignoring the rules. So the quickest workaround you can make is to disable the lint check for Timber.

Open your `build.gradle` file and add this:

```
android {
  lintOptions {
  disable 'TimberArgCount', 'TimberArgTypes', 'TimberTagLength', 'BinaryOperationInTimber', 
  'LogNotTimber', 'StringFormatInTimber', 'ThrowableNotAtBeginning'
  }
}
```

You can check Timber's lint rules [in here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber/blob/master/README.md#lint).

For more info on lintOptions, [read the docs here](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptions.html).
For more info on the disable option, [read it here](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptions.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptions:disable).

Comment: This doesn't address my question. I've already solved the problem for my project. I want to know what I can contribute to the open source library so this isn't necessary.

Comment: If that's the case, SO isn't the best place to do so. Go to the project page, open an issue, and submit the pull request.

Comment: The question is what to put in the PRQ. Or in general, how to prevent Timber from leaking out of a library.